# Capturing an event On Sketch Finish in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.3, polygon-creation

I am using IEditEvents_Event and IEditor. I invoked the GarciaUI_CreateNewFeatureTask and used:

```
pID.Value = "esriEditor.SketchTool";
pCommandItem = pCommandBars.Find(pID);
if (pCommandItem != null)
{
  pCommandItem.Execute();
}
```

It is working and I can create a polygon in edit mode. I want to capture an event after the Polygon Creation is completed.

I also have another button on the same form to Split Polygon. I want to capture an event after the split is completed. But I want to capture both these events separately. Can someone help me to accomplish it?

I have to do it in c# + ArcObjects ArcGIS 10.3.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking out aloud here, you could the IEditEvents.OnSketchFinished Event to capture the completion of the edit. As you can only have one active tool (IApplication) you could retrieve that and query which tool is active and respond accordingly.

Comment: Exact, you acn find more information here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002000000128000000